# PC randomly reboot during gaming (temps are ok)

Tags: windows-10, reboot, gaming

My PC randomly reboots while gaming.

Sometimes it happens in menu without launch a game, sometimes 5 min after start, sometimes 3-6 hours or none - no pattern there.

It happens in 3 of 4 games I'm playing currently:

```
Euro Truck Simulator 2 (4-5 hours)
American Truck Simulator (0-5 min)
Natural Selection 2 (1-3 hours)
```

PC Rig:

```
CPU AMD Ryzen 3 3100
GPU NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4GB Low Profile MSI
PSU Corsair SF450 450W (changed from Chieftec CSN-650C 650W - not helped)
MotherBoard MSI B550M PRO-VDH WiFi (came back from guarantee - not found any issue with that part, it’s 100% ok)
RAM GoodRam IRDM X DDR 4 1x16GB 3200MHz CL16 (changed from HyperX - not helped)
SSD AData SwordFish 1TB
4 fans 80x80
```

Max temps (during games):

```
MotherBoard: 48C
CPU: 59C
GPU(hot spot): 78C
SSD: 40C
```

There is a log from last reboot:

```
The system was rebooted without a clean shutdown first. Possible causes of the error: The system has stopped responding or has crashed, or there has been an unexpected loss of power.

Nazwa dziennika:System

Źródło: Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power

Data: 31.05.2021 15:22:00

Identyfikator zdarzenia:41

Kategoria zadania:(63)

Poziom: Krytyczne

Słowa kluczowe:(70368744177664),(2)

Użytkownik: SYSTEM

Komputer: DESKTOP-3SAEVNN

Opis:

System został uruchomiony ponownie bez uprzedniego czystego zamknięcia. Możliwe przyczyny błędu: system przestał odpowiadać lub uległ awarii albo nastąpiła nieoczekiwana utrata zasilania.

XML:

<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08...>

<System>

<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" />

<EventID>41</EventID>

<Version>8</Version>

<Level>1</Level>

<Task>63</Task>

<Opcode>0</Opcode>

<Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords>

<TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-05-31T13:22:00.5246757Z" />

<EventRecordID>24024</EventRecordID>

<Correlation />

<Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />

<Channel>System</Channel>

<Computer>DESKTOP-3SAEVNN</Computer>

<Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />

</System>

<EventData>

<Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data>

<Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data>

<Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data>

<Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data>

<Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data>

<Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data>

<Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data>

<Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data>

<Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data>

<Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data>

<Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">0</Data>

<Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">0</Data>

<Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">false</Data>

<Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data>

<Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2">0</Data>

<Data Name="LongPowerButtonPressDetected">false</Data>

</EventData>

</Event>
```

I have no idea how to fix it now. Please help.

#Update 1

MemTest86 Result:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

#Update 2

Last error before critical failure above:

```
Nazwa dziennika:System
Źródło:        EventLog
Data:          31.05.2021 15:22:06
Identyfikator zdarzenia:6008
Kategoria zadania:Brak
Poziom:        Błędy
Słowa kluczowe:Klasyczny
Użytkownik:    Nie dotyczy
Komputer:      DESKTOP-3SAEVNN
Opis:
Poprzednie zamknięcie systemu przy 15:03:23 na ‎31.‎05.‎2021 było nieoczekiwane.
Kod XML zdarzenia:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="EventLog" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">6008</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-05-31T13:22:06.2440042Z" />
    <EventRecordID>24014</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-3SAEVNN</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>15:03:23</Data>
    <Data>‎31.‎05.‎2021</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>8</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Binary>E507050001001F000F0003001700FF02E507050001001F000D0003001700FF023C0000003C000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Check for a hardware/RAM problem by running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for as many hours as you have patience. Overnight is recommended.

Comment: @harrymc I used 3 different types of ram, and with all of them I have same issue, I tested pervious one and this one too.

Comment: You need more information for finding the problem, so start with examining the Event Viewer for errors and [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1652727/edit) any new data into your question. Running MemTest86 (when you have time for it) checks more than just the RAM.

Comment: @harrymc I posted log from Event Viewer above - there is nothing?

Comment: That message is from after the reboot, so not helpful.

Comment: @harrymc Ok, i will try after memtest, which log is before?

Comment: @harrymc and I should edit post or add answer with newer details? (atm 2nd memtest86 pass and 0 errors)

Comment: @harrymc Uploaded memtest result

Comment: I need the whole file for full conclusions. How many passes did you do?

Comment: I added last error before critical. Where I can found this file (im not specialist in it)

Comment: @harrymc there is a file https://file.io/Vddkh9okrs1R

Comment: It only ran 2 full passes (the first is a quick pass), but it seems you don't have a hardware problem as regarding memory, CPU and memory-controller. You also don't seem to have a heating problem. It might a problem with the electrical network of the house. Do you have a UPS or a surge protector?

Comment: @harrymc yes, I have one UPS, but I disconnected it already but it not helps much, but I think there can be an issue because ... my ps4, MacBook, PC, notebook and all displays (4k, 2k and 1k) are connected to one electrical contact. Tonight I trying to play on different electrical contact for this PC, but it's still one room ( I think I have too many things in one room)

Comment: Sometimes this can be caused by some electrical appliance that kicks in using a lot of current, such as the fridge or washing machine. Check what other appliances are on the same circuit as your room.

Answer (score 0):

Since the fault seems to be in *Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power*, you might check your power supply. Perhaps it can't keep up with heavy CPU and GPU demands from gaming.

Comment: I used app to calculate and calculator to manually calculate on a website, and my TDP is around 230 , in games to 290 so even when I use gold 450W I should have around 410 to use. Simple math: 410 - 290 = 120 left to use, so it shouldn't be this, especially when perviously I used 650W gold too with more power to use.

Comment: Not every supply performs according to specifications. Also, electrolytic capacitors age.